# Negate global parameter in dhcpd.conf

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, dhcp-server

Let's say I've got a DHCP server that will serve 10 subnets.  9 of the subnets will be on the "example.org" domain and one will receive no domain from the DHCP server.  I set

```
option domain-name "example.org"
```

as a global parameter in dhcpd.conf.  In the specific subnet that I don't wish to give a domain to I can override the global parameter by specifying a new one in that specific block.

My question, however, is how would I completely negate that global parameter for the subnet, rather than specifying a more specific parameter for that subnet?